# Norm of difference of two squares of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $x,y$ be square matrices and $c$ be any scalar.

Is it true that $ \Vert x^2 \Vert - c^2 \Vert y^2 \Vert = \Vert x - cy \Vert ^2$?

If this is true then I'm done with the proof of a theorem on association theory. Thanks.

Note: $\| x \| = \langle x,x\rangle$  and $\langle x,y\rangle = \operatorname{Trace} (x  y^*)$ where ${}^*$ is the conjugate and transpose of $y$.

Comment: What is $x^2$? And what norm are you using?

Comment: || x || = <x,x>. And <x,y> = Trace (x times y*) *=conjugate and transpose. Where x and y are square matrices

Comment: @DGR: Ok, in your question you wrote "vectors" instead of "matrices">  You can edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming per the comment that $x,y$ are matrices and $\|\cdot\|$ is the Frobenius or Hilbert-Schmidt norm:

No, this is not true.  Try taking $c=1$, $x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.  The left side is zero but the right side is not.